# How to use AsyncLocalStorage for an Observable?

Tags: node.js, rxjs, nestjs, async-hooks

I'd like to use use [AsyncLocalStorage](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/async_hooks.html#async_hooks_class_asynclocalstorage) in a [NestJs Interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#aspect-interception):

```js
export interface CallHandler<T = any> {
    handle(): Observable<T>;
}
export interface NestInterceptor<T = any, R = any> {
    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler<T>): Observable<R> | Promise<Observable<R>>;
}
```

The interceptor function gets a `next` `CallHandler` that returns an `Observable`.

I cannot use [run](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/async_hooks.html#async_hooks_asynclocalstorage_run_store_callback_args) in this case (the run callback will exit immediately before the `callHandler.handle()` observable has finished):

```js
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, callHandler: CallHandler): Observable<any> | Promise<Observable<any>> {
    const asyncLocalStorage = new AsyncLocalStorage();
    const myStore = {  some: 'data'};
    return asyncLocalStorage.run(myStore, () => callHandler.handle());
  }
```

See [broken replit-example](https://replit.com/@MartinTrummer/asyncHooks-run#index.js)

The solution I came up with is this:

```js
const localStorage = new AsyncLocalStorage();

export class MyInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, callHandler: CallHandler): Observable<any> | Promise<Observable<any>> {
    const resource = new AsyncResource('AsyncLocalStorage', { requireManualDestroy: true });
    const myStore = { some: 'data' };

    localStorage.enterWith(myStore);
    return callHandler.handle().pipe(
      finalize(() => resource.emitDestroy())
    );
  }
}
```

See [working replit example](https://replit.com/@MartinTrummer/asyncHooks-newAsyncResource)

This seems to work fine, but I am not sure if this is really correct - and it looks messy and error-prone. So I wonder:

1. Is this correct at all?
2. Is there a better/cleaner way to handle this?

Comment: _"I cannot use run in this case (the run callback will exit immediately before the callHandler.handle() observable has finished)"_ <-- Can you expand on this? Based on my reading of the docs for `AsyncLocalStorage.run()`, it returns whatever its callback does, synchronously. The observable can't be subscribed to before `run` completes, because `run` returns the observable. What specifically isn't working for you with that approach?

Comment: @backtick: the store is undefined when using run: I'll add some links to replit examples

Answer (score 2):

here is our current solution to the problem:

- we create an observable that will simply pass all emissions to the `callHandler`
- the important part is, that we subscribe **inside** the `localStorage.run` method

```js
const localStorage = new AsyncLocalStorage();

export class MyInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, callHandler: CallHandler): Observable<any> | Promise<Observable<any>> {
    const myStore = { some: 'data' };

    return new Observable((subscriber) => {
      const subscription = localStorage.run(myStore, () => {
        /**
         * - run the handler function in the run callback, so that myStore is set
         * - subscribe to the handler and pass all emissions of the callHandler to our subscriber
         */
        return callHandler.handle().subscribe(subscriber);
      });
      /**
       * return an unsubscribe method
       */
      return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the reason of returning an unsubscribe method ?

Comment: When the caller of the `intercept` function wants to abort execution, they call `unsubscribe`. In this case our Observable should also stop all the work ASAP: i.e. we must unsubscribe from the observable that we have subscribed to (the one returned by `handle()`). For more details see: https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable#disposing-observable-executions

Answer (score 1):

Below is the solution I came up with.  My understanding of the problem is that you need the `run` function to receive a callback function that will fully encapsulate the execution of the handler, however, the `intercept` function is expected to return an observable that has not yet been triggered.  This means that if you encapsulate the observable itself in the `run` callback function, it will not have been triggered yet.

My solution, below, is to return a new observable that, when triggered, will  be responsible for triggering (i.e. subscribing to) the call handler itself.  As a result, the promise we create in the `run` call can fully encapsulate the handle function and it's async callbacks.

Here is the general functionality in a stand-alone function so that you can see it all together:

```
intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler<any>): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable((subscribe) => {
        asyncStorage.run({}, () => new Promise(resolve => {
            next.handle().subscribe(
                result => {
                    subscribe.next(result);
                    subscribe.complete();
                    resolve();
                },
                error => {
                    subscribe.error(err);
                    resolve();
                }
            );
        }));
    });
}
```

Next, I took that concept and integrated it into my interceptor below.

```
export class RequestContextInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    constructor(
        private readonly requestContext: RequestContext,
        private readonly localStorage: AsyncLocalStorage<RequestContextData>
    ) {}

    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler<any>): Observable<any> {
        const contextData = this.requestContext.buildContextData(context);
        return new Observable((subscribe) => {
            void this.localStorage.run(contextData, () => this.runHandler(next, subscribe));
        });
    }

    private runHandler(next: CallHandler<any>, subscribe: Subscriber<any>): Promise<void> {
        return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
            next.handle().subscribe(
                (result) => {
                    subscribe.next(result);
                    subscribe.complete();
                    resolve();
                },
                (err) => {
                    subscribe.error(err);
                    resolve();
                }
            );
        });
    }
}
```

It's worth noting that the `Promise` that is created during the `run` call does not have a rejection path.  This is intentional.  The error is passed on to the observable that is wrapping the promise.  This means that the outer observable will still succeed or error depending upon what the inner observable does, however, the promise that wraps the inner observable will always resolve regardless.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue related to this : https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/11142.
AsynclocalStorage will be suppported in NestSJ 10.0.0.

Comment: Seems that it will be available from the box. Sounds great!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for [cls-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cls-hooked):

```
return new Observable(observer => {
  namespace.runAndReturn(async () => {
    namespace.set("some", "data")   
    next.handle()
        .subscribe(
          res => observer.next(res), 
          error => observer.error(error),
          () => observer.complete()
        )
  })
})
```